# regex to extract data from xml nodes in php

Tags: php, xml, regex

Here is the XML

```js
<us:ItemMaster>
     <us:ItemMasterHeader>
        <oa:ItemID agencyRole="Product_Number">
           <oa:ID>9227950</oa:ID>
        </oa:ItemID>
        <oa:ItemID agencyRole="Prefix_Number">
           <oa:ID>AAG</oa:ID>
        </oa:ItemID>
        <oa:ItemID agencyRole="Stock_Number_Butted">
           <oa:ID>5035</oa:ID>
        </oa:ItemID>
        <oa:ItemID agencyRole="Manufacturer_Sku_Number">
           <oa:ID>5035</oa:ID>
        </oa:ItemID>
     </us:ItemMasterHeader>
</us:ItemMaster>
```

I want to extract the **Product_Number, Prefix_Number, Stock_Number_Butted and Manufacturer_Sku_Number**.

Can you advice how to do it using regex in php?

I don't want to use xml parser for this, that is getting very lengthy, as i have so many large xml files to process.

Thanks!

---

### **Update:**

**For those who are seeking the same**
Found **[xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)** is the best way to proceed and i found this link very helpful.
Here is the code:

```php
<?php 
echo "<pre>";
$info = array();
$xmlStr = file_get_contents("http://officedealersolution.highviews.co.cc/sftp/ecdb.individual_items/AAG5035.xml");
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr); 
$res = $xml->xpath("//us:DataArea/us:ItemMaster/us:ItemMasterHeader/oa:ItemID[@agencyRole=\"Product_Number\"]/oa:ID"); 
$info['Product_Number'] = $res[0];
$res = $xml->xpath("//us:DataArea/us:ItemMaster/us:ItemMasterHeader/oa:ItemID[@agencyRole=\"Prefix_Number\"]/oa:ID"); 
$info['Prefix_Number'] = $res[0];
$res = $xml->xpath("//us:DataArea/us:ItemMaster/us:ItemMasterHeader/oa:ItemID[@agencyRole=\"Stock_Number_Butted\"]/oa:ID"); 
$info['Stock_Number_Butted'] = $res[0];
$res = $xml->xpath("//us:DataArea/us:ItemMaster/us:ItemMasterHeader/oa:ItemID[@agencyRole=\"Manufacturer_Sku_Number\"]/oa:ID"); 
$info['Manufacturer_Sku_Number'] = $res[0];
print_r($info);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [Product_Number] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 9227950
        )

    [Prefix_Number] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => AAG
        )

    [Stock_Number_Butted] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 5035
        )

    [Manufacturer_Sku_Number] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 5035
        )

)
```

Here is a very good xpath tutorial by w3schools **http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp**

Comment: this question has been asked many times. Long story short you can use regex for simple cases; but a parser is indicated

Comment: Eschewing the most appropriate tool is not very sensible. What regex have you tried? (Else it sounds like you are just asking for code when it was your decision to go the cumbesome route.)

Comment: This can be done using a few lines of code with an XML parser. Producing a regex that works as well will be a lot longer and much less comprehensible.

Comment: SimpleXML is enough for this job. See my answer.

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs, finally i found an answer, hopefully good technique, but if you think there is something better than this then please do post.     
    
Instead of using regex, i found that xpath is the best way to proceed and i found this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) very helpful.

Comment: Cannot post the code due to character limits. Here is the link to it: [http://codepad.viper-7.com/7FXAd9](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7FXAd9)

Answer (score 1):

When all you use is a hammer, everything looks like a nail.

Regex is completely the wrong tool for the job. Use one of PHP's XML extensions (such as DOMDocument) instead.

Comment: you are right but for some reason my xml is not parsed correctly. Please take a look at the xml [here](http://officedealersolution.highviews.co.cc/sftp/ecdb.individual_items/AAG5035.xml)  

Whenever i am trying to parse it using different parsers, it ends up with some complications and different results. All i need is to access the following information:  

`<oa:ItemID agencyRole="Product_Number">  
<oa:ID>9227950</oa:ID>  
</oa:ItemID>`

I need data from the nodes that has attributes: **Product_Number, Prefix_Number, Stock_Number_Butted and Manufacturer_Sku_Number**

Answer (score 1):

If the file is *valid* XML, the following code will get what you want *assuming `$data` contains the XML data as string*.

```
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($data);
$nss = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
$us = $xml->children($nss['us']);
$im = $us->ItemMaster;
$imh = $im->ItemMasterHeader;
$oa = $imh->children($nss['oa']);

$parsed_data=array();

foreach($oa->ItemID as $item_id){
    $attr = $item_id->attributes();
    $role = (string)($attr->agencyRole);
    $id = (string)($item_id->ID);
    $parsed_data[$role] = $id;
}

print_r($parsed_data);
```

Comment: Thank you for code, it seems promising, here is the link to the XML [XML Link](http://officedealersolution.highviews.co.cc/sftp/ecdb.individual_items/AAG5035.xml)

It is giving me this error:
`Fatal error:  Call to a member function children() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\watsint\reg.php on line 12`

Comment: Yes, My code will not work because the code I have written is for the sample you have given to me on the question. For the original XML file it'll be little bit different.

Comment: thank you for your help, found xpath my best shot. Here is the working link [http://codepad.viper-7.com/7FXAd9](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7FXAd9)        Let me know if you think there is enhancement possibilities.